# sending drawn line through bluetooth not working well Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-bluetooth, uibezierpath

I am building an app that uses UIBezierPath and bluetooth to let people draw on each others devices.  Almost everything is working well (all be it a little slow in transmission.
I use TouchBegan, TouchMoved, and TouchEnded to send that information to the other computer and then say when touchBegan string = TouchBegan then draw the same line continuously passing over the x and y coordinates.
The problem lies in the receiving device when the first line is started (touch began) and when the pencil is picked up (touch ended)on the first device and put down (touch began again)in another spot.  On the first (sending device) everything works as it should.  However on the receiving device a line is drawn between where the pencil is picked up (touch ended) and where the new line is started (touch began). This even happens when the pencil is first placed on the screen.
The weird thing is that when I go from the sending device is a newer iPhone 7 to an older iPad mini II it happens much more than when I go from the older device to the newer one.
I am not including code because basically I use the UIBezierPath method to draw the lines on one layer (temp layer) and then when the touch ended I say that to another layer and erase the temp layer. As I said I use touchBegan, touchMoved and touchEnded on the sending device and then notify the receiving divide of these events via bluetooth and have the same thing happen on the receiving device using UIBezierPath.
My question is there any way to reset the  touch so the receiving or sending device has no last know position of the touch (touchEnded I guess)?
If anyone has any suggestion I am willing to try anything.

I am including an image to show what is happening.

[image]

Comment: I think the tool you're looking for here is `UIBezierPath.move(to:)`. That moves the point without drawing a line to it. That said, it sounds like you may be dropping packets over BLE. You should add logging to make sure you're receiving everything you're sending (and that you're drawing exactly the same thing you're sending).

Comment: I have used this.  When the touchBegan happens on device one it send that information to device two.  Then I use when touchString is equal to @"touchBegan" then Path. move to  (the touch began coordinates).  This works fine when I am sending from the iPad Mini II to the iPhone 7 but not the other way around.  I even create a delay in the other direction and it take a full second to have the iPad register the TouchBegan.  I think that the iPad mini II is so old and slow that it can't process the incoming info fast enough and so the move:to isn't implemented.